# Registrations Allowed From Pending From Wait List While Event Maximum Attendee Number Has Been Exceeded

Tags: civievent, registration, waitlist

Using pending from wait list allows a person to complete their registration using the special link in their Confirm Your Registration email while we are over an event maximum by a small number attendees.  However, if we are  over the maximum by a dozen or more, the person instead gets an event is full message when using their pending from wait list link.

The number of registrations where the event is full message displays on the registration page, and the number of registrations where clicking the Confirm Your Registration email link results in a event is full message instead of the Confirm your registration message, is not the same number.

Why are these numbers different?  The current registrations minus cancellations and transfers seem to be calculated differently for these two purposes.  We are using all the default positive and negative count settings for registrations and cancellations.

In any case, I would expect registrations to still be allowed by attendees who are pending from wait list and not be restricted by the maximum count.

This issue was also raised in https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5093